# Open Instagram Threads in my Swift project but not work

Tags: ios, swift, url

I searched on many websites and as well as StackOverflow but I couldn’t any output for this

I use this function to open Instagram in Swift Project and it works properly.

```
guard var screenName = self.instagramLabel.text, screenName.count > 0 else { return }
      if screenName.hasPrefix("@") {
                screenName.removeFirst()
            }
            let appURL = URL(string: "instagram://user?username=\(screenName)")!
            let application = UIApplication.shared
            if application.canOpenURL(appURL) {
                application.open(appURL)
            } else {
                guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.instagram.com/\(screenName)/") else { return }
                self.openWeb(url)
            }
```

Now I do this for open Instagram's Threads application but it not working

```
guard var screenName = self.threadsLabel.text, screenName.count > 0 else { return }
            if screenName.hasPrefix("@") {
                screenName.removeFirst()
            }

            let appURL = URL(string: "threads://user?username=\(screenName)")!
            let application = UIApplication.shared
            if application.canOpenURL(appURL) {
                application.open(appURL)
            } else {
                guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.threads.net/\(screenName)/") else { return }
                self.openWeb(url)
            }
```

For that just remove

```
URL(string: "instagram://user?username=\(screenName)")!
```

and add

```
URL(string: "threads://user?username=\(screenName)")!
```

But it did not work and executed else part

Hope I got the answer

Comment: I think this might help https://www.reddit.com/r/one_sec/comments/14tsxjd/anyone_figure_out_the_url_scheme_for_threads_yet/

Comment: Did you add `threads` to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key of your Info.plist?

Answer (score 2):

The "URL Types" (CFBundleURLTypes) is the property that controls which schemes will open your application.

To allow opening another app, use LSApplicationQueriesSchemes:

[image]

Essentially, your definition is saying that barcelona:// links should open your app but you are not allowed to use them inside the app.

example how to use:-

```
let appURL = URL(string: "barcelona://user?username=\(Yourusername)")!
            let application = UIApplication.shared
            if application.canOpenURL(appURL) {
                application.open(appURL)
                return
            }
            else {
                guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.threads.net/\(Yourusername)/") else { return }
                self.openWeb(url)
                return
            }
```